# Background image in bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a bootstrap modal when user comes to my website.
I want to use a Background image in modal so that it will look good.
I tried a lot but i am not able to set a background image in my bootstrap modal.
So can any one help me.

my css-

```
.modal-dialog{
    background-image: url("static/markatix/imgs/modal/bg.png");
      }
```

my modal code is-

```
      <div class="modal-content" >
    <div style="padding:5px 5px;">

        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" style="padding:4px 50px;">
      <p id="new_notification1" >Hello User</p>
        <p id="new_notification2">How are you?</p>
        <form name="form" method="post" action="{% url "visitors" %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <p align='left'><label for="id_phone_number">Phone number:</label><br> <input id="id_phone_number" name="phone_number" type="text" pattern="[0-9]{10}" required/></p>
          <input type="hidden" name="shop_id" value={{shop.id}}/>
          <button class="btn2modal" type="submit">Login with Facebook</button>
        </form>
      </div>
          <div >
             <div class="modal-body" style="padding:4px 50px;">
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this , use background image to `.modal-content` class

```css
.modal-content {
 background:url('https://cdn.techinasia.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Doodle4Google-2010-Group-1-Winner.jpg');
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Can i use two images together

Comment: You might be better off doing this inline, directly on that element because that URL is now hard-coded. <div class="modal-content" style="<?php echo bloginfo('url); ?>/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/Doodle4Google-2010-Group-1-Winner.jpg">

Comment: @vikrantVerma yes of course you can use two images together

Answer (score 0):

In your code `modal-dialog` class is nowhere present.

Try applying image to `modal-boy`

```
.modal-dialog{
    background-image: url("http://imgh.us/boardroom_1.jpg");
      }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/27805/)**

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```css
.modal-body{
 background-image: url("http://www.w3schools.com/css/trolltunga.jpg");
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
```